# Php page not showing properly if warnings and deprecated notices present on the page

Tags: php

I am working on the php code using Wamp server.Normally when errors or warnings present in our web page while enabling "display errors" in php settings,the page content will come with those errors.

But in my page when "cannot modify header information" warning came, nothing is displayed.Only blank page.

To remove the warning message I tried all the possibility which I gone through in web.

But nothing happened.

[image]

Why it is blank and how to get rid of "header error"? please any one suggest me on this

Comment: If you want your code to work disable error reporting else you have to replace in your code the usage of all mysql_ methods, as its deprecated (as its written) . Valid libraries for mysql today are mysqli_ and PDO ..

Answer (score 1):

**Why is this happening?**

The entire ext/mysql PHP extension, which provides all functions named with the prefix mysql_, is officially deprecated as of PHP v5.5.0 and will be removed in the future.

It was originally introduced in PHP v2.0 (November 1997) for MySQL v3.20, and no new features have been added since 2006. Coupled with the lack of new features are difficulties in maintaining such old code amidst complex security vulnerabilities.

The manual has contained warnings against its use in new code since June 2011.

**How can I fix it?**

As the error message suggests, there are two other MySQL extensions that you can consider: MySQLi and PDO_MySQL, either of which can be used instead of ext/mysql. Both have been in PHP core since v5.0, so if you're using a version that is throwing these deprecation errors then you can almost certainly just start using them right away—i.e. without any installation effort.

They differ slightly, but offer a number of advantages over the old extension including API support for transactions, stored procedures and prepared statements (thereby providing the best way to defeat SQL injection attacks). PHP developer Ulf Wendel has written a thorough comparison of the features.

Hashphp.org has an excellent tutorial on migrating from ext/mysql to PDO.

I understand that it's possible to suppress deprecation errors by setting error_reporting in php.ini to exclude E_DEPRECATED:

error_reporting = E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED
What will happen if I do that?
Yes, it is possible to suppress such error messages and continue using the old ext/mysql extension for the time being. But you really shouldn't do this—this is a final warning from the developers that the extension may not be bundled with future versions of PHP. Instead, you should take this opportunity to migrate your application now, before it's too late.

Note also that this technique will suppress all E_DEPRECATED messages, not just those to do with the ext/mysql extension: therefore you may be unaware of other upcoming changes to PHP that would affect your application code. It is, of course, possible to only suppress errors that arise on the expression at issue by using PHP's error control operator—i.e. prepending the relevant line with @—however this will suppress all errors raised by that expression, not just E_DEPRECATED ones.

**What should you do?**

You are starting a new project.

There is absolutely no reason to use ext/mysql—choose one of the other, more modern, extensions instead and reap the rewards of the benefits they offer.

You have (your own) legacy codebase that currently depends upon ext/mysql.

It would be wise to perform regression testing: you really shouldn't be changing anything (especially upgrading PHP) until you have identified all of the potential areas of impact, planned around each of them and then thoroughly tested your solution in a staging environment.

Following good coding practice, your application was developed in a loosely integrated/modular fashion and the database access methods are all self-contained in one place that can easily be swapped out for one of the new extensions.

Spend half an hour rewriting this module to use one of the other, more modern, extensions; test thoroughly. You can later introduce further refinements to reap the rewards of the benefits they offer.

The database access methods are scattered all over the place and cannot easily be swapped out for one of the new extensions.

Consider whether you really need to upgrade to PHP v5.5 at this time.

You should begin planning to replace ext/mysql with one of the other, more modern, extensions in order that you can reap the rewards of the benefits they offer; you might also use it as an opportunity to refactor your database access methods into a more modular structure.

However, if you have an urgent need to upgrade PHP right away, you might consider suppressing deprecation errors for the time being: but first be sure to identify any other deprecation errors that are also being thrown.

**You are using a third party project that depends upon ext/mysql.**

Consider whether you really need to upgrade to PHP v5.5 at this time.

Check whether the developer has released any fixes, workarounds or guidance in relation to this specific issue; or, if not, pressure them to do so by bringing this matter to their attention. If you have an urgent need to upgrade PHP right away, you might consider suppressing deprecation errors for the time being: but first be sure to identify any other deprecation errors that are also being thrown.

It is absolutely essential to perform regression testing.

Comment: blah blah blah blah blah it's not answering the real question: the headers error.

Comment: The entire ext/mysql PHP extension, which provides all functions named with the prefix mysql_, is officially deprecated as of PHP v5.5.0 and will be removed in the future.

Comment: And yet, again, not answering the real question.

Comment: can you please sent me here error details , or screenshot

Comment: Hi all.Actually my concern is the actual content of my page is not displaying.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow you are trying to send an HTTP header through the use of the function 'header'. But to use that function you need that nothing else has been written to output before. Unfortunately something was already sent, and it was those mysql warnings. Get rid of them, and you'll get rid of the later.